# How to hide a paragraph in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("para").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("para").style.display = "none";
```

None of the above works, however the funny thing is if I want to make a paragraph visible using javascript I can just use:

```
document.getElementById("para").style.visibility = "visible";
```

And that would make it visible, why cant it be hidden using the same method?

HTML:

```
<p style="visibility: hidden" id="para">Message has been sent</p>
<p style="visibility: visible" id="emailUs">Email Us!</p>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("para").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("emailUs").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

UPDATED see link below:

https://jsfiddle.net/mym23kLr/1/

Comment: Above code should work, Can you show the HTML?

Comment: updated pls have a look

Comment: When exactly is the JS executed?

Comment: Your first code works: `document.getElementById("para").style.visibility = "hidden";`

Comment: @Teemu once a button is pressed, checks are made and if everything is fine the above javascript is executed, the "para" visibility works, but the "emailUs" to hidden doesnt!

Comment: Interesting, can you create a [mcve].

Comment: @Teemu will do give me 5 mins

Comment: @Teemu I tried adding a version that works here https://jsfiddle.net/mym23kLr/1/ but for some reason im getting errors, however there is a bit more code there which you might understand better what im tryign to do

Comment: Mhh, too much errors in your fiddle. At least the `id` of the `#emailUs` is missing. [This is a minimal example](https://jsfiddle.net/38fbebsa/), only that it shows, that the code works, hence the problem can't be reproduced with the code in the post.

Comment: Oh sorry I did have the ID for #emailUs on my real original code, but miss typed it here :( I have no idea then why the original code is not working

Comment: I doubt being mobile would stroke that code. Make sure your functions are actually called, i.e. they are global.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155584/discussion-between-luke-and-teemu).

Answer (score 1):

I've created a code snippet with working example, added a toggle button:

```js
function toggle() {
  if (document.getElementById("para").style.visibility === "visible") {
    document.getElementById("para").style.visibility = "hidden"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("para").style.visibility = "visible"
  }
  if (document.getElementById("emailUs").style.visibility === "hidden") {
    document.getElementById("emailUs").style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("emailUs").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }

}
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', toggle);
```

```html
<p style="visibility: hidden" id="para">Message has been sent</p>
<p style="visibility: visible" id="emailUs">Email Us!</p>
<button id="myButton">
  Toggle
</button>
```

Comment: Thats kinda how my code looks like, have a look at the link i provided. however I cant run in here for some reason https://jsfiddle.net/mym23kLr/1/

Comment: Sorry but i cant fill the form in

Comment: I got that error too, i been trying to figure it why its happening. but either way, once the form is submited, the paragraph with "email Us" should disapear and the "message has been send" be visible, the "message has been sent" gets visible but the "email us" doesnt get hidden.

Comment: I think, problem is with validation. You just should make a console.log of document.getElementById("para") and see is it undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can do in below way as well :

To show para : document.getElementById("para").style.opacity = "1";

To hide para : document.getElementById("para").style.opacity = "0";

Answer (score 0):

Basically both are correct, but the difference between display = "none" & visibility = "hidden" is that. With display "none" the element is removed from the layout of elements on the page. With visibility "hidden" the element still occupies its space, you just don't see it anymore. And also move script tag to the bottom of page.  It's good practice to have the  tags right before the closing  so all the elements are already present in the page and you don't need to worry about wrapping code in.

Answer (score 0):

This html `<p style="visibility: hidden" id="para">Message has been sent</p>` have visibility set to hidden so it is no way visible in the screen.

So `document.getElementById("para").style.visibility = "hidden";` will not make any difference

Comment: That does get visible in the screen, if you see the Javascript section below I set it to visible. The above code was simply an example.